# ActionScript 3 - Error #2044: Unhandled securityError:. text=Error #2048: Security sandbox violation

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3

I seem to have a problem and can't get it work. I'm working on a simple application that comunicates with som php scripts to manage databases. While my app is simple and still in development, I have gotten it to work on my pc. This although changes when I upload it to my webserver.

The page is:

http://converter-vhs-para-dvd-video.info/GestaoCCBS/CCBS%20Management.html

and the swf:

http://converter-vhs-para-dvd-video.info/GestaoCCBS/CCBS%20Management.swf

First, it appears to be normal, but when you press the "Login" button, nothing happens, doesen't login and doesent throw out an error for not being correct.

After some fiddling around, I noticed that ONLY Firefox gives me an error:

```
Error #2044: Unhandled securityError:. text=Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: http://converter-vhs-para-dvd-video.info/GestaoCCBS/CCBS Management.swf cannot load data from http://www.converter-vhs-para-dvd-video.info/GestaoCCBS/CheckLogin.php.
    at LoginModule/CheckLogin()
```

I tried messing with the "Acess local files only/Acess network" option in the publish menu, but still no dice.

Can anyone please help me? I bet its a simple error, but i'm still new to this.

Also, keep in mind i'm working with php scripts, and not xml (Don't know if it makes a difference).

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the code where you call CheckLogin.php?

Comment: No need, Kodiak answered my problem. It was stupid too (the problem).
Thanks though. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the URL has a `www` and not the other, you may want to harmonize these.

Comment: Oh god, do I feel stupid now. That was all it took. The same exact link with the "www." behind now works. I can't believe I spend almost one hour stumped with this. Well thanks, you rock. :)

Comment: Sometimes you just have to get your head out of it and show it to someone else ;) Could you accept my answer then?

Comment: Done. I actually tried it ealier and had a warning saying I had to wait like 3 more minutes to accept it and just forgot about it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `Security.allowDomain("domain.com");` ?
Edit: looks like an other answer solved your problem. Nice! :-)